# Use Last modified date in search results

Tags: search, search-results

After few hours I still dont know how to do the following: Customer wants to display last 5 documents with search engine. I am able to write the query and also order the documents by modified date. However I am not able to fetch the modified date to search results. I can take the write element property however client wants also the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.searchresultsbasewebpart.dateformat.aspx) property is used for specifying the date and time formatting for the [CoreResultsWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497469.aspx) web part.

By default search results in the web part are displayed in [DateOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms414006) format.

### Usage

> This property could not be specified using web part editor, so please
>   consider another options for specifying it value, for example
>   SharePoint Designer.

For example, after specifying this property value to `DateTime`:

```
<property name="DateFormat" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPDateFormat, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">DateTime</property>
```

`write` property would be displayed like this:

```
<write>2/12/2013 12:58 PM</write>
```

Comment: Where should I put that <property>?

Comment: It could not be specified via Web Part Tool,but there are another options that allows to provide this property:
1)via SPD
2)Export web part, specify this property and add it on page again
3)during web part provisioning

Comment: To anyone else wondering, with SPD, you should have it as a attribute of the WebControls:CoreResultsWebPart, like this: <WebControls:CoreResultsWebPart DateFormat="DateTime" ... >